# How do I append a value to results of @DBlookup in xpages?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How do I append a value to results of @DBlookup in xpages?

I tried this but it does not seem to work.

var v = @DbLookup("","Setup","Setup","ModRationales").push("Other 2");
  return v;

It shows 6.0 in my listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

var v = @DbLookup("","Setup","Setup","ModRationales");

v.push("Other");

return v;

Comment: Just remember that this does not work if the var v is a String. See Per Henrik Lausten's answer about the return type of @DbLookup().

Answer (score 6):

First of all: @DbLookup returns a string when it looks up one value only, and it returns an array when it finds multiple values. I will therefore suggest that you use [the DbLookupArray() function available as a xsnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique) as this function always returns an array. It has other advantages too such as optional caching of the result.

Then it is just a matter of adding elements to the array using .push() on the result returned by DbLookupArray().

Your current lookup is most likely returning a single element - which in the case of @DbLookup is a string.

Comment: Try @List(@DbLookup(...), "Other")